# Entity Framework One to Many Generates an Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a database with 2 classes, and I have a one to many relationship set up. This is set up as a shop (the main class I am running my code against, which is joined in my db to a list of categories of products that shop sells.

So the tables are;

```
shops 
int          id        //shopId & primaryKey
varchar(50) shopName  
...                    //other details left out.

ShopProductTypes
int          id       //Category id
int          ShopId   //Foreign Key to shop table
varchar(50)  CategoryName  
...
```

This is all straighforwards, and works through sql viewer etc a treat.

I have imported the database model, and unbchecked the Pluralize / Singularize box.

my context is;

```
 public ReportingContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
        {

            Database.SetInitializer<ReportingContext>(null);

        }

      protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
      }

        public DbSet<AutoComp_Reporting.DAL.Shop> Shops{get; set;}

        public DbSet<AutoComp_Reporting.DAL.ShopProductTypes> ShopCategories { get; set; }

    }
```

but when I run;

```
var foo = (from s in context.Shops
          where (s.Id == id).select s).toList();
```

I can see all the shops, but if I try to look at the categories in QuickWatch, I get the follwoing exception

> {"An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the
>   inner exception for details."}

```
System.Data.EntityException {System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException}
```

Unwinding that eventually reveals;

```
    Message "Invalid column name 'Shops_Id'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Shops_Id'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Shops_Id'."
```

I may well be doing something wrong as I am new to entity framework, but I cannot fix this error.
I have got `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` in my database connection string.

So how do I track down the cause of this error, and / or fix it? I am guessing that the actual inner exception is down to the way that the framework is interpreting the properties, so may be a red herring..

Comment: Your error message states `Shops_Id`, whereas in your table definition it shows as `ShopId`.

Comment: I know, I assumed that was an artefact of the framework to be honest, as the model i am using in my code was generated from the database. Or are you saying that each time I import / update the model I will need to edit the auto generated code so that the id's match what the framework is expecting? It seems a pretty poor framework if it is trying to force me to redesign an existing database to fit its expectations!

Comment: can you post ShopProductTypes code ?

Comment: I agree, but it's the one thing that I would definitely check out first, since it the most obvious cause for the exception.

Comment: [Column("ShopId", TypeName="int")]
   public String Shops_Id {get;set;}

Comment: may be the above modification helps you if my guess is correct !!

Comment: @Ramesh. the code is auto generated from visual studio, and the class is simply the propertiers I detailed above, with the same names.

Comment: that's okay. if we want to find out what is the cause. so we needs some of the manual modification. Later on, we will decide how to take care while auto generation. can you just update me that piece of code from your autogenerated class ?

Comment: @ramesh. I now get;
{"Invalid column name 'Shops_Id1'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Shops_Id1'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Shops_Id1'."} System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

Comment: please post the ShopId property for better help

Comment: [Column ("ShopId", TypeName="int")]
        public int Shops_Id { get; set; }

Comment: [ForeignKey("ShopsId"), Required]public int Shops_Id { get; set; }

Comment: [ForeignKey("ShopsId"), Required]public int Shops_Id { get; set; } 
Produces a reduced error message of;
{Invalid column name 'Shops_Id'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Shops_Id'."} System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Is it worth taking this to chat to avoid spamming the comment thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the name of the Foreign Key in the table, and applying the ForeignKey attribute seems to have worked. However I am sure that this is not the correct solution, else it means that the framework only works out of the box if you have a database that has been built to a specific naming convention.

Bearing in mind this is a legacy application, how do I fix this issue once and for all?